# Windows Service start error error 193 0xc1 after converted to VC2012 on win2k3

Tags: c++, windows, service, atl

I have ATL service with COM out-of-proc interface running perfectly when using VC2010 compiler on Windows Server 2003, uptodate. After compiling with VC2012 service do not start, giving me this message: Error 193: 0xc1.

Any suggestion ?  On the internet I found nothing useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652199/servicebase-service-error-1930xc1-on-windows-xp

Comment: This project not use .Net 4.5. It is C++ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution on this link [Windows XP Targeting with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx).
After change in option "Platform Toolset" to "Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)", the service start normally.