# deploying windows service make

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-services

This is an image of the server that I am deploying my windows server on it

[image]

the service is installed, but when I run it, I got this exception:

```
Could not start the XXXX service on local computer.
Error 193:0xc1
```

#### I don't know what information should I give you, but what ever you want I can tell

#### Note

I am building on x86

#### App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
some connection strings here ....
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

#### plus

is there any way so i can check log of that service?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.fixerrs.com/2014/03/Steps-to-Fix-Error-193-0xc1.html#.VEj-kBYehv4

Comment: @Marton I checked the log and I am getting `service is not a valid win32 application` though I debug using `x86` what should I do please?

Comment: Is there a file named Program in your SystemDrive folder? (C:\Program usually)

Comment: @Marton there is program file, not program, does that matter?

Comment: See what happens if you rename the 'program' file to something else.

Comment: @Marton I can't rename the program file, it is a server for a big big company. please can you read my irst comment in the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You must have compiled your exe either for .Net 4.5 or for 64-bit architecture (or both). This is the explanation of error code you run into from WinError.h:

// %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
//
#define ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT             193L
Make sure you have compiled it for x86 platform or Any CPU, and whatever version of .Net Framework you compiled against is installed on the machine.
```

(from [ServiceBase service error 193:0xc1 on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652199/servicebase-service-error-1930xc1-on-windows-xp) ).

Windows Embedded usually never come with 4.0/4.5 framework installed (depends on who made image), so trying to install framework may help.

Note : Windows Embedded Standard (2009) is the updated version of Windows XP Embedded, the fully componentized version of Windows XP Professional and the successor to Windows NT 4.0 Embedded.

Comment: I have comploied using `x86`, and the .net is 4.5. and I can see this folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` which means that I have .net 4.5 installed right?

Comment: http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-net-framework-452-offline-installer-available-for-download - try installing, but I'd recompile for 4.0 - windows embedded 2009 is based on windows xp - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx (not supported).

Comment: I changed to .net 4, I am trying now and will update you

Comment: changing to 4 is the solution YESSSSSSSSSSSS